# How to convert date value to Date only in View form

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list-view

[image]

I want to display only date and remove extra 22:00:00Z value. Dont know why it is appearing in View form as i am using only Date in this column type.

Answer (score 2):

**For SP 2010**

You can edit it with SharePoint designer > then convert it to data view > edit date to look like

```
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(string(@StartDate), 1033, 3)"/>
```

The syntax is

```
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(string(@StartDate), [LCID],[FORMAT FLAG])"/>
```

**For SP 2013**

Got List Settings > Click on your date column name to modify it > select date only > Check Display format Friendly.

[image]

Comment: Always go with changing it to Date Only from Date & Time even if it is SP 2010.

Comment: At his quest. he said he has already set it as Date only and  not worked

Comment: earlier :  <xsl:value-of select="@Start_x0020_date_x0020_of_x0020_" />                                Now:     <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(@Start_x0020_date_x0020_of_x0020_, 1033, 3)" />                             This is giving error,is syntax correct?

Comment: Are you sure the internal name end with _ and look like  Start_x0020_date_x0020_of_x0020_

Comment: yes it ends with _ . Is there any workaround for this , using sharepoint designer2010

Comment: Didn't notice that. You can also try <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(@Start_x0020_date_x0020_of_x0020_, 1033, 'yyyy-MM-dd')"/> .This will give you date only in YYYY-MM-DD format

Comment: try to surround your field with string to look like this  ddwrt:FormatDate(string(@myDate), 1033, 3)